# Неотрабатывают границы радиуса

Tags: c++, qt, логика

не могу достичь понятного результата

смысл такой :
с начала проверяю пересекают ли границы от рисовки  линии в  ноль (0, 360)
если пересекают то отрабатывает  `if( angle >= poz_start || angle <= poz_end)`*(вот тут всё работает как надо)*

если нет то `if( angle >= poz_start && angle <= poz_end)`

почему то этот код `if( angle >= poz_start && angle <= poz_end)`   не отрабатывает почему то он выводит код даже в случае   `angle < poz_start` и  `angle> poz_end`

Не могу понять что делать ??

```
    float angle = _value; // угол (0, 360)

    bool bool_null = false;
    float prov_null = _border - _border_start;
    if(prov_null < 0){
        prov_null = prov_null + 360.0;
        bool_null = true;
    }

    if(bool_null == true)
    {

        if( angle >= poz_start || angle <= poz_end)
        {
            p->rotate(angle);

            p->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
            p->setPen(QPen(_colorItem, 1.6*_thickness, Qt::SolidLine));
            //    p->drawEllipse(QPointF(0,0),r*0.3, r*0.3);
            p->drawLine(QPointF(0,0), QPointF(0,0 - r*0.3));
            p->rotate(-angle); // возвращаем назад точку отчёта
        }
    }
    if(bool_null == false)
    {
        if( angle >= poz_start && angle <= poz_end)
        {
            p->rotate(angle);

            p->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
            p->setPen(QPen(_colorItem, 1.6*_thickness, Qt::SolidLine));
            //    p->drawEllipse(QPointF(0,0),r*0.3, r*0.3);
            p->drawLine(QPointF(0,0), QPointF(0,0 - r*0.3));
            p->rotate(-angle); // возвращаем назад точку отчёта
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас под условиями идентичный код. Как Вы отличаете, какая ветка выполнилась? Что касается условий: для угла в диапазоне должно быть ```( angle >= poz_start && angle <= poz_end)```, для угла вне диапазона: ```( angle < poz_start || angle > poz_end)``` Но на текущий момент я не  понимаю, как должен был работать Ваш код.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Здравствуйте Юрий спасибо что уделили моему вопросу время , добавил пояснения в виде рукописного теста , так бы не смог описать.

Comment: Где и как определяются ```poz_start``` и ```poz_end```? Чему они равны на момент проверок? Для чего введена переменная ```prov_null```?  К сожалению, пока не могу до конца понять логику Вашего кода. И загляните, пожалуйста, [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)